# How to click button of a WebElement in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I was trying to automate content save functionality in the following website, but 'Save' button is not getting clicked, though element is identified and code has been written to click on the button using Actions class and Javascriptexecutor.

```
<div class="btn_post">
            <a href=""><img onclick="return false;" id="tempsaving_btn" src="btn_btemporarysave.gif" width="67" height="25" title="" alt="Temporary save"></a> 
            <a href="#" onclick="oCafeWrite.showPreview(); clickcr(this, 'wrt.preview', '', '', event); return false;"><img id="cafePreviewbtn" src="btn_bpreview.gif" width="67" height="25" alt="preView">
            </a> <a href="" onclick="Editor.$('textbox').execCommand('checkEmbedObjectTag'); oCafeWrite.preCafeWriteContents(); return false;">
        <img id="cafewritebtn" src="btn_bconfirm.gif" width="57" height="27" alt="Confirm">
                </a>
            <div class="rbtn"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Post the code you tried. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Could you show that code that "has been written"? Thanks.